# Getting no application can do this action on Android while using Codename One share button

Tags: share, codenameone

My Codename One app features a `ShareButton` that is used like this :

```
 // Share this report on social networks (text plus screenshot)
    ShareButton shareReportButton = new ShareButton();
    shareReportButton.setText("Share this report!");
    shareReportButton.getAllStyles().setBorder(
                    RoundBorder.create().rectangle(true));
    FontImage.setMaterialIcon(shareReportButton, FontImage.MATERIAL_SHARE);
    shareReportButton.getStyle().setBgColor(ParametresGeneraux.accentColor);
    shareReportButton.getPressedStyle().setBgColor(ParametresGeneraux.darkPrimaryColor);

    shareReportButton.setTextToShare("I reported this via the great app ABCD "!"
    );
    shareReportButton.setImageToShare(currentReport.getPhotoPath(), ImageIO.FORMAT_PNG);
```

I works as expected under the simulator but on an actual Android 4.4 device I get a Dialog menu with "No app can do this action".

[image: Cannot share text with image]

Please note that it is possible to share eg a photo with the native apps.

I could not find any build hint to add [in the doc](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/advanced-topics.html#_sending_arguments_to_the_build_server). What should I do to make the share button offer a way to share a text + photo on the social networks ?

Any help appreciated,

Regards

**EDIT**

Following @James H and @Diamond answers, the image type has to be set as mime type. Consequently replacing ImageIO.FORMAT_PNG by "image/jpg" makes the share menu populated.

For completeness please notice that as stated in the doc

> an image must be stored using the FileSystemStorage API and shouldn't use a different API like Storage!

So even if the photo is in the cache you have to copy it eg to your home folder and then use this copied version in the ShareButton.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem might be that

```
setImageToShare(String imagePath, String imageMimeType)
```

is looking for a Mime description with a different format, such as: "image/png"

I'm not sure that ImageIO.FORMAT_PNG works in this way. Looking at the sample in the JavaDoc, it uses:

```
sb.setImageToShare(imageFile, "image/png");
```

Comment: Hi James H, thanks a lot, it works better now. I used "image/png" or "image/jpg" and was able to see the share menu populated! The photo is not attached but text is already there!

Comment: I'm not sure if both image and text are supported. I think it's either/or.

Comment: Hi @Shai at least on Android 4.4 it is possible to share text along with an image and that's nice!

Comment: You can share text and image with ShareButton on both Android and iOS.

Comment: In the past there was an either/or mode, I think Chen fixed it at some point.

Answer (score 2):

Use the native share functionality and check if sharing natively is support by doing the following:

```
// Share this report on social networks (text plus screenshot)
Button shareReportButton = new Button("Share this report!");
shareReportButton.getAllStyles().setBorder(create().rectangle(true));
FontImage.setMaterialIcon(shareReportButton, FontImage.MATERIAL_SHARE);
shareReportButton.getStyle().setBgColor(ParametresGeneraux.accentColor);
shareReportButton.getPressedStyle().setBgColor(ParametresGeneraux.darkPrimaryColor);
shareReportButton.addActionListener(e -> {
    if (Display.getInstance().isNativeShareSupported()) {
        Display.getInstance().share("I reported this via the great app ABCD ", currentReport.getPhotoPath(), "image/png"); // Or "image/jpg"
    } else {
        ToastBar.showErrorMessage("Your phone doesn't support sharing...");
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi Diamond and also thanks alot! Your solution works too, although the photo is not attached (the photo filename shows cacheXYZ.jpg with 1.3KB). I'll have to check what the picture is like. By the way what's the benefit of using the native share over what @James H suggested ?

Comment: `ShareButton` requires you to add other services you want that are not present by default, but `Display.getInstance().share()` allows sharing through all available ShareServices on a device without adding them individually.

Comment: By service you mean Twitter, Facebook, Email, ... On my device both solutions offer a list of services to use, so I don't understand your explanation. Would you mind elaborating ?

Comment: Well, I maybe wrong then... previously I had to do `shareReportButton.addShareService(share)` to add non-existing services, that might have changed.

Comment: Oh yes, I had nothing special to do on Android. All services were already there! Anyway thanks for your explanation. I'll mark James H 's answer as correct because it is the closest to my code, but yours was good too.